# Who is Mizuki Kusanagi's father?

Tags: the-sky-crawlers

Mizuki Kusanagi is Suito Kusanagi's daugher who is about to outgrow her soon.

At first I thought her father would be Kurita Jinroh. However he only arrived at the base 7 months prior to the start of the movie. Does this mean:

1. Suito Kusanagi has been alive since Mizuki was born? And the father is unknown?
2. Mizuki grows very fast?